# Unknown chromium error: -6

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing a mobile app using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile. When I'm calling a function that contains a `$.get` call in it I get the dreaded `Unknown chromium error: -6` error.

```
$.get(apiurl, {
    'action' : 'get_mobile_content',
    'request' : 'search_jobs'
}, function(data) {
    console.log("inside");
}, 'json');
```

I never get to the output of `console.log("inside")`. Please advise.

Comment: Try looking at the network pane and see if the request was sent? and what is returned. I would guess its some sort of a parsing issue of what you return.

Comment: @epeleg thanks, figured it out already :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem. I'm stupid. But the actual technical details of the problem are that the `apiurl` was the wrong url, and didn't return anything I guess. Once this was fixed to store the correct url, the problem was solved.